# Create message draft using Slack API?

Tags: slack-api

Is it possible to "draft" a message using API? There is draft_id param in chat.postMessage, but I just don't understand how to use it.

UPD: It's not possible =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no documented API to create draft messages in Slack.
I would suggest dropping a mail to slack and ask about your specific use case.